How to access a wiki from a private repository that was public on github?
I have a private repository on github that was once public. When it was public he had a project wiki. Now that it's private I can't access the wiki anymore because it says I must upgrade the pro plan to activate the functionality.
Is this wiki saved in some git folder system that I can simply access or did I lose everything that was documented until the repository became private?


You can try cloning the wiki repo with git clone https://github.com/your/repository.wiki, but I don’t know if that will work while it’s private; might have to make it briefly public to do that.

@Ry- confirmed, this will work.
